# PJSIP get Info error

Tags: pjsip, pjsua2

when I make phone call through PJSIP framework, I used PJSIP library

https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android/blob/master/examples/demoapp/app/src/main/java/net/gotev/sipservicedemo/MainActivity.java

here is the Error I get from C++ trace
                                       #05 pc 0012c633  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN9__gnu_cxx27__verbose_terminate_handlerEv+226)
03-14 15:56:39.449 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #06 pc 001272e9  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv111__terminateEPFvvE+4)
03-14 15:56:39.449 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #07 pc 0012735d  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZSt9terminatev+8)
03-14 15:56:39.449 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #08 pc 00127365  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZN10__cxxabiv112__unexpectedEPFvvE+4)
03-14 15:56:39.450 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #09 pc 00126993  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (__cxa_call_unexpected+42)
03-14 15:56:39.450 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #10 pc 00099023  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (_ZNK2pj4Call7getInfoEv+418)
03-14 15:56:39.450 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #11 pc 00088d0b  /lib/arm/libpjsua2.so (Java_org_pjsip_pjsua2_pjsua2JNI_Call_1getInfo+38)
03-14 15:56:39.450 23788-23788/? A/DEBUG:     #12 pc 024221b1 /oat/arm/base.odex (offset 0x21b8000)

Comment: this Call is active but can't get current state

Comment: the callee will get the phone call, but caller application crashed

Comment: this is outgoing call

Comment: Please follow official PJSIP documentation to properly build the library - [Getting Started: Building for Android](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/Android).

Answer (score 1):

If you are following PJSIP open source library. you can download their project and compile the project for android and you can use it with android studio easily.

Please check the following link to develop your PJSIP project in android or iOS,

[Integrate pjsip in iOS app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44179718/integrate-pjsip-in-ios-app)

Comment: Hello Siva, the problem has been solved, this issue cause by the header buffer size, but thanks for your help though.