# Integrate pjsip in iOS app

Tags: ios, voip, pjsip

I am Goosip/AKSSIP for pjsip wrapper but not able to connect to the server. Can any one guide me to implement pjsip in iOS project.

Thanks!

Comment: You're have to provide more details, including the relevant parts of your code, and any errors or logs.

Comment: After creating a User agent when making a call with outgoingCallToUri through Goosip Wrapper:

I got below errors:

Gossip: ringbackWithSoundNamed: (null)
pjsua_aud.c  .Unable to create playlist: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND) [status=70006]

Gossip: Error Domain=pjsip.org Code=240006 "Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)" UserInfo={PJSIP_ERRNO_FORM_SIP_STATUS=240006, NSLocalizedDescription=Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND), pj_status_t=70006}

Comment: XPC connection interrupted

pjsua_call.c  .Unable to generate Contact header: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT) [status=171060]

Gossip: Error Domain=pjsip.org Code=341060 "Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)" UserInfo={PJSIP_ERRNO_FORM_SIP_STATUS=341060, NSLocalizedDescription=Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT), pj_status_t=171060}

Comment: Please update your question with properly formatted code.

Comment: please check your header info that passed to the pjsip. It shows that unSupportedTransport in contact header passed to pjsip. which transport are you using? TCP or UDP ?

Comment: HI @NandhaKumar , I am using UDP.  Gossip: ringbackWithSoundNamed: (null)
09:30:41.700    pjsua_aud.c  .Unable to create playlist: Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND) [status=70006] <br/>Gossip: Error Domain=pjsip.org Code=240006 "Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND)" UserInfo={PJSIP_ERRNO_FORM_SIP_STATUS=240006, NSLocalizedDescription=Not found (PJ_ENOTFOUND), pj_status_t=70006}<br/>Gossip: dispatchCallState(0)
09:32:52.299 tsx0x7fed5e0ae !.......Temporary failure in sending Request msg INVITE/cseq=27060 (tdta0x7fed5f014000), will try next server: Unsupported transport (PJSIP_EUNSUPTRANSPORT)

Comment: HI @NandhaKumar , When I make call then console prints:  Gossip: dispatchCallState(0)
Gossip: dispatchCallState(0)
Gossip: dispatchCallMediaState(0)
Gossip: dispatchCallState(0)
Gossip: dispatchCallState(0)

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh did you pass your domain in correct format to PJSIP? Like <sip:username@ip:port>

Answer (score 3):

**To Integrate PJSIP on iOS:**
**step 1:** First Download PJSIP Project from their website.
http://pjsip.org/download.htm

**step 2:** Extract the files in your computer.

**step 3:** Go to the folder pjsip2.6/pjlib/include/pj/

**step 4:** create config_site.h file

**step 5:** add the following lines into the config_site.h file
and save the file

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_IPHONE 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

**step 6:** open command prompt and go to your pjproject2.6 path.
For Example, *User/nandha/Documents/pjproject2.6/*

**step 7:** compile following commands in command prompt.

```
./configure-iphone
```

After successfully compiled above command , execute next command.

```
make dep && make clean && make
```

If both command executed properly means, your PJSIP project is successfully integrated with your iOS and ready to run your project in iPhone.

Source:https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

The above documentation clearly shows how to integrate PJSIP on iOS.

Comment: Hi @Nandha , Thanks for the answer, I have already did that. But could not able to figure out. How do I integrate it in my existing project and How to start using the pjsip code. If you can guide me some initial steps to do that. It will help me a lot.

Comment: please mention what you did, and what input you gave to the PJSIP and what error occurs. If you clearly post your problem, then its easy to solve the problem.

Comment: I have compile the pjsip library from above mentioned steps , then simply open **pjsip-apps/src/pjsua/ios/ipjsua.xcodeproj** , and after run the app , got the error **No architectures to compile for (ONLY_ACTIVE_ARCH=YES, active arch=armv7s, VALID_ARCHS=armv7).** after resolving this error I got another 196 errors. For those you can [visit](https://xianwen.me/2017/04/08/how-to-make-an-ios-voip-app-with-pjsip-part-1/) , I have posted here.

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh Are you using iphone or simulator for testing? please follow the pjsip documentation instructions for compiling the library.https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone

Comment: I am using iPhone, and I had follow the same steps.

Comment: click your projects target and go to build settings, change build active architecture only options into "NO" and change valid architecture into "armv7".

Comment: Hi @NandhaKumar , I have succeed to eliminate those errors but now I am struggling in setting end point and give proxy. Please look into the below code which I have done till now.  But in response I got <br/>  pjsua_acc.c  ....IP address change detected for account 0 (192.168.2.34:5080 -->  Updating registration (using method 4). <br/>
sip_auth_clien  ...Unable to set auth for tdta0x10117d400: can not find credential for d0c20d13-e5b4-4649-821e-9ab8ec94b141/Digest. <br/>
pjsua_acc.c  ....SIP registration error: No suitable credential (PJSIP_ENOCREDENTIAL) [status=171101]

Comment: @KaramjeetSingh It shows that you passed wrong values for SIP registration. Like as username,uri,algorithm for authentication. Try Same SIP registration by some other voip dialer and check what it shows. ex. LINPHONE Dialer .

Comment: @NandhaKumar , Hey I am struggling with Mac linker error . My code is not compiling . Can you guide me . Where I am wrong . I have follow the steps go Pjsip : All project is  made by steps but not able to compile it . Please help me where I am wrong

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia Please give me the detail about problem, where you got the error when compiling and what error occurs?

Comment: @NandhaKumar I followed the commands as given in Pjsip site and missing part was for my simulator then I solved that issues .. Now on my simulator it is showing me Port number : My next questions is how to integrate it , in my app (which is of swift ) how to do it . and where I have to configure my server . can you help me here

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia sure. ip port is showing in the screen is used for CLI. In CLI you can register and call through CLI commands. Did you have server to Register and Calling through SIP?

Comment: Yes , right now , I am using the local machine as a server , But plus is that I have my credentials of live server . I was following the PJSip .. and thier it create a objective c code in its library . Now I want to to all those stuff in my swift project ,do you have any reference link to do that . or any other suggestions that can help in my. flow

Comment: @VijayvirSingPantlia Just convert those objectiveC Files into Swift files. did you able to call C methods from swift files.

Comment: @NandhaKumar Can we you chat on hangout .. at virvijay37@gmail.com

Comment: @NandhaKumar Or skype me at virvijay37 , I shall be very thank full for your this